# hide update summary dialog Advanced Installer

Tags: windows, updates, auto-update, advanced-installer

I am using Advanced Installer to update my application. I am doing it with the help of "Check for updates using Advanced Updater" option under "Updater" pane. This adds the "update.exe" in the "Application Folder".

When I run this update application on the client PC, it checks for the update in the server and prompts the update summary(See the image below).

[image: UpdateSummaryScreenShot]

But I need to hide this from the user.
Is there any way to do this? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this with the help of [command line options](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/updater.html).